# How to set prop with generic type array?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have a select component and what I am trying to do is to implement the component in that way so I can pass an array of any type. How can this be done? Where should the generic be defined? I am using `<script setup>`  with typescript.

This is how I tried to define the props:

```
const props = defineProps<T[]>({
    options: {type: Array as PropType<T[]>, required: true }
})
```

Comment: this makes no sense in my eyes. trying to pass an generic type. what do you want to achive ?

Comment: I don't want to be forced to use only a specific type, instead, it would be nice to use any type I want.

Comment: then `const props = defineProps<{ options: any[] }>()` this ?

Comment: Unfortunately generics (I mean generic components) is something without support in Vue currently

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using TypeScript, Vue allows you to do this:

```
const props = defineProps<{
    options: T[];
}>();
```

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```js
const props = defineProps<{
  options: string[],
}>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic prop types like so:

```html
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends string, U extends Item">
import type { Item } from './types'

defineProps<{
  id: T
  list: U[]
}>()
</script>
```

Learn more: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#generics